# data from values file lost when I pass parameter in template file in hele

Tags: kubernetes-helm

That's how I passed variable to template file

```
{{ template "fluentd-config" (dict "replica" "bbcc" "pattern" "aabb"  ) }}
```

and here is template file

```
{{- define "fluentd-config" -}}
image: {{ .Values.fluentd.kinesis_image }}
myname: {{ .replica }}
pattern: {{ .pattern }}
{{- end -}}
```

and when I run it, `.Values.fluentd.kinesis_image` gone null. Please let me know how to resolve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a Go `text/template` template, the special variable `.` is the parameter to the template.  Also remember that the syntax `.foo` means looking up the field `foo` in the object `.`.  So in this context, the template parameter replaces the Helm global object; `.Values` tries to look it up in the dictionary you're passing as a parameter.

One solution to this is to also pass in `.Values` at the call site (if you need any of the other top-level Helm objects you also need to manually pass those in):

```
{{ template "fluentd-config" (dict "replica" "bbcc" "pattern" "aabb" "Values" .Values) }}
```

A more complex pattern I've used is to pass a list as the template parameter, and then extract fields out of that.  You can use the [Sprig list functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/lists.html) to construct and deconstruct the list.  (You could do something similar with [`dict`](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/dicts.html) to have named parameters and that might be syntactically simpler.)

```
{{- define "fluentd-config" -}}
{{- $top := index . 0 -}}
{{- $params := index . 1 -}}
image: {{ $top.Values.fluentd.kinesis_image }}
myname: {{ $params.replica }}
pattern: {{ $params.pattern }}
{{- end -}}

{{- $params := dict "replica" "bbcc" "pattern" "aabb" -}}
{{ template "fluentd-config" (list . $params) }}
```

Comment: It's perfect though. Even it's correct answer, it's required for me to fix some changes. `  {{- $top := index . -}}` and `{{- $params := index . "replica" -}}`. anyway, thanks.